# Sum of multiple array elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have multiple arrays in javascript and I want to do sum of those arrays and final array.

```
EX: Array1 = [1,9,10,11], Array2 = [5,8,7,2], Total = [6,17,17,13].
```

Comment: I don't really understand, what your problem is, you want to find the best solution from a performance perspective?

Comment: What is the "final array"? Do you want `1+9+10+11 + 5+8...`, or do you want `[1+5+6, 9+8+17, ...]`

Comment: I tried creating one function.. MyArray.Sum() which is returning sum of all array elements.. but I want one final array which consists of sum of all passed multiple array elements shown in above example.

Comment: Array1 = [1,9,10,11], Array2 = [5,8,7,2], Result = [6,17,17,13].  Result is sum of array1 and array2 elements.

Comment: “Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it” (http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), voting to close.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var Array1 = [1,9,10,11];
var Array2 = [5,8,7,2]; 
var Total = [];

for( var i = 0; i < Array1.length; i++)
{
    Total.push(Array1[i]+Array2[i]);
}
```

BTW, starting variable names in capital letters feels awkward.

Answer (score 6):

Pure function with multiple arrays:

```js
function sum(arrays) {
  return arrays.reduce((acc, array) => acc.map((sum, i) => sum + array[i]), new Array(arrays[0].length).fill(0));
}

const arrays = [
  [4, 6, 3, 2],
  [1, 4, 7, 9],
  [4, 6, 3, 2],
  [1, 4, 7, 9]
];

const result = sum(arrays);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Your one-liner is very good! I went into the *Edit* mode to play with it in the preview without saving and I got to understand it better, this was very useful

Answer (score 1):

```
var Array1 = [1,9,10,11];
var Array2 = [5,8,7,2];
var Total = new Array();
for(var i= 0;i<Math.min(Array1.length,Array2.length);i++){
  Total.push(Array1[i]+Array2[i]);
}
alert(Total);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function aSum(/*arrays list*/){
  var total=[],undefined;
  for(var i=0,l0=arguments.length;i<l0;i++)
    for(var j=0,arg=arguments[i],l1=arg.length;j<l1;j++)
      total[j]=(total[j]==undefined?0:total[j])+arg[j];
  return total;
}


var Array1 = [1,9,10,11], Array2 = [5,8,7,2], Array3 = [1,2,3,4,8];

console.log(aSum(Array1, Array2, Array3)); // [7, 19, 20, 17, 8]
```

Answer (score 1):

Arrow function in ES6

```js
var Array1 = [1,9,10,11];
var Array2 = [5,8,7,2]; 
var sum = Array1.map((val, idx) => val + Array2[idx]);

console.log(sum);
```